# Change function acting on sum to function acting on each object individually

Tags: list-manipulation

Given a function like `Conjugate[]` acting on a sum, how I can change an expression like

```
Conjugate[ 6 I Sqrt[2] h1L1Ri Y1L + 6 Sqrt[2] h1L1Rr Y1L + Y15L (3 I Sqrt[2] h15i[3] + I Sqrt[6] h15i[8] + I Sqrt[3] h15i[15] + 3 Sqrt[2] h15r[3] + Sqrt[6] h15r[8] + Sqrt[3] h15r[15])]
```

to

```
Conjugate[ 6 I Sqrt[2]] Conjugate[ h1L1Ri] Conjugate[ Y1L] + Conjugate[6 Sqrt[2]] Conjugate[ h1L1Rr ] Conjugate[ Y1L] + Conjugate[ Y15L ] ( Conjugate[3 I Sqrt[2]] Conjugate[ h15i[3]] +...)],
```

i.e. that now `Conjugate[]` acts on each object in the sum individually?

Answer (score 3):

```
expr = 6 I Sqrt[2] h1L1Ri Y1L + 6 Sqrt[2] h1L1Rr Y1L + 
  Y15L (3 I Sqrt[2] h15i[3] + I Sqrt[6] h15i[8] + I Sqrt[3] h15i[15] + 
     3 Sqrt[2] h15r[3] + Sqrt[6] h15r[8] + Sqrt[3] h15r[15]);
Map[Conjugate, expr, {2}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

If you really want each term, you can expand first

```
Map[Conjugate, Expand@expr, {2}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Added:

Thanks to Kuba suggestion, you can also use, for general case

```
 Map[Conjugate, Expand@expr, {-1}]
```

Comment: In case of more complex expression OP will probably need `Map[Conjugate, expr, {-1}]`.

Comment: @Kuba yes, I forgot above the `-1`, thanks for point it out. But `Expand@expr` is still needed as well.

Answer (score 2):

You can be quite flexible using replacement rules such as

```
rules = {Conjugate[u_Plus]:>Conjugate/@u, Conjugate[u_Times]:>Conjugate/@u}
```

This is then applied as required, e.g.

```
expr //. rules
```